# Securing an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm trying to apply the least privilege principle to an Azure Function. What I want is to make a FunctionApp have only read access to a, for example, storage queue. What I've tried so far is:

- Enable managed identity in the FunctionApp
- Create a role that only allows read access to the queues (role definition below)
- Go to the storage queue IAM permissions, and add a new role assignment, using the new role and the Function App.

But it didn't work. If I try to write to that queue from my function (using an output binding) the item is written, when I expected a failure. I've tried using the builtin role "Storage Queue Data Reader (Preview)" with the same result.

What's the right way to add/remove permissions of a Function App?

Role definition:

```
{
  "Name": "Reader WorkingSA TestQueue Queue",
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "Read TestQueue queue on WorkingSA storage accoung.",
  "actions": ["Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/read"],
  "dataActions": [
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/messages/read"
  ],
  "notActions": [],
  "notDataActions": [],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/TestAuth-dev-rg"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The queue that you are trying to write to, is that storage account the same account that the Function App is using ? Also, are you sure that the Storage Key is not being configured somewhere and is being used. Further I am not sure that the Azure Queue binding is configured to work with Azure Storage AAD. What you have to do is to assign the MSI the role  you created and use the MSI to access the queue. Also read this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-preview-of-aad-authentication-for-storage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@anirudhgarg has pointed the right way.

The managed identity and RBAC you set makes difference only when you use [managed identity access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity?toc=%2fazure%2fazure-functions%2ftoc.json#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources) to reach Storage service in Function app. It means those settings have no effect on function binding as it internally connects to Storage using [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-for-an-azure-storage-account). If you haven't set [connection property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#output---configuration) for the output binding, it leverages the [AzureWebJobsStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings) app settings by default.

To be more specific, connection string has nothing to do with Azure Active Directory Authentication process so it can't be influenced by AAD configuration. Hence if a function takes advantage of Storage Account connection string(e.g. uses Storage related binding), we can't limit its access with other settings. Likewise, no connection string usage means no access.

**Update for using SAS token**

If the queue mentioned is used in a Queue Trigger/input binding, we can restrict function with read and process(get message then delete)access, here comes [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-using-a-shared-access-signature).

Prerequisite:

1. Queue locates at Storage account other than the one specified by AzureWebJobsStorage app setting. AzureWebJobsStorage requires connection string offering full access with Account key.
2. Function app is 2.0. Check it on Function app settings> Runtime version: 2.xx (~2). In 1.x it requires more permissions like AzureWebJobsStorage.

Then get SAS token on portal as below and put it in app settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JerryLiu,

Then, if I've understood correctly, if we're using the storeage binding for the queue, we can't rely on the AAD to control the permissions. 

I guess the same applies if I try to use the .Net API, as I need a connection string there. 

Will it work if I use a Shared Access Signature as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-using-a-shared-access-signature)?

Comment: Thanks @Jerry-Liu. Last question: does that mean that I can only give the same permissions to all the queues in the storage? Is there any way to give different permissions to different queues?

Comment: @vgaltes Use different connection strings for different queue bindings. For example, in a queue output binding we can use another sas connection string with Read and Add permission.

Comment: Are the function triggers still unable to use RBAC security to connect to storage and event hubs?